# Application Insights to azure webjob .Net Core 2.0

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

How to add application insights telemetry (Application Insights) to azure webjob ?

Comment: could you please clarify which kind of azure webjob, web job template or console application or .net core console app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With recently released WebJob SDK 3.0, you can add ApplicationInsights in the **ConfigureLogging** method

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     var builder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices().AddAzureStorage();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
        {
            // Adding command line as a configuration source
            b.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
            b.AddConsole();

            // If this key exists in any config, use it to enable App Insights
            string appInsightsKey = context.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
            {
                b.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey);
            }
        });

     var host = builder.Build();
     using (host)
     {
         await host.RunAsync();
     }
}
```

Comment: This was helpful since most of the documentation uses `JobHost.AddApplicationInsights()` and not the `HostBuilder` API (see docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#add-application-insights-logging) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration)). However, all the documentation says to use `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` for the config key instead of `ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey`. I'm guessing it's because the former key is the default key that Azure uses when adding through Azure wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can add AI to Web Jobs during the development time as a Nuget Package.

AI .NET Core Nuget is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.5.0-beta1). Package name is a bit misleading (`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`) but it's supposed to work with all .Net core apps.

AI .NET Core GitHub page is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore) (with some customization options explained in Wiki).

Getting started guide is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started) and [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-core) as well. It's a bit lengthy guide, so I hope links are OK (although not in full accordance with SO guidelines) and I won't need to post it as part of the reply.