# Application Insights for .NET Core Azure WebJob

Tags: .net-core, azure-webjobs

When I try to setup my .NET Core WebJob to use Application Insights, I get the following Exception on startup:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions'.'

I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but I can't find it out. My Main method is like in many examples, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424215/application-insights-to-azure-webjob-net-core-2-0)

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        Configuration.EnvironmentName = environment;
        Configuration.IsDevelopment = string.Equals(environment, "Development");

        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.UseHostId("ecad61-62cf-47f4-93b4-6efcded6")
                .AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                .AddAzureStorage()
                .AddTimers()
                .AddEventHubs();
            })
            .ConfigureServices(x => ConfigureServices(x))
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
            {
                b.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false);
                b.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", true);
                b.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration.Config = b.Build();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConfiguration(Configuration.Config);
                b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                b.AddConsole();
                b.AddDebug();
                //TODO fix applicationInsights
                string appInsightsKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
                {
                    b.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey);
                }
            })
            .Build();

        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance (and true shot in the dark), I would check to see if `context.Configuration` this throwing the exception because **APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY** doesn't exist in the collection. The missing key could be throwing an exception that's bubbling up to your DI container.

EDIT: Trying giving this package a try and let me know if works. It's currently in pre-release. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights/

EDIT: The call to AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry uses DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions is dependent on IHostingEnvironment. IHostingEnvironment isn't used by the [WebJobsSDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) which is causing your exception. The WebJobsSDK has it's on usage of Application Insights and you should be able to use it similarily to https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/dev/sample/SampleHost sample

Comment: Hi! This line actually wasn't quite right, because I'm working with this Configuration.Config object. But anyway it worked, and was not the problem. 
I tried to create my own IHostingEnvironment object, and add it in the ConfigureServices method, but that doesn't solve it either.

Comment: Would you mind posting the nuget packages your project is referencing? I'm trying repo the issue but missing some dependencies and I want to make sure I'm using what you're using.

Comment: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.1"
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.4
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.1"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.2"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.3"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" Version="3.0.4"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.4"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.3.0"

Comment: "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.2.0"

Comment: I didn't run into any noticeable issues with your Main(). What does `ConfigureServices(IServicesCollection x)` do?

Comment: Hi Ryan! Sorry I didn't answer yet. the ConfigureServices is just setting up DependencyInjection. Because I use two different applications that share the same core assemblies, I created that function. A little C&P:
services.AddDbContext<EntityContext>(options =>
            {
                var connStr = Configuration.GetDbConnectionString();
                options.UseSqlServer(connStr, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Backend.Data"));
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
            services.AddTransient<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with this DI setup. It's just weird that the ApplicationInsights doesn't setup correctly.

Comment: Hi @StefanR. let me know if that nuget package helps any.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Hill. I get the same error with that nuget package
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions'.'

Comment: @StefanR. what's the full stack trace?

Comment: had to send it as 'answer' because of the length

Comment: Impossible to send the stacktrace as comment, and they deleted my answer.

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I haven't been able to repo your issue. I followed the steps outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started followed by adding the missing packages you listed above the project bit by bit and I still haven't run into runtime exceptions. I even tried a random instrumentation AI guid thinking that may have been the issue but still no exception.

If you only needing to run WebJob host, you don't necessarily need many of those packages. I've got my csproj listed below.

Comment: netcoreapp2.1
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.4"
"Microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions" Version="3.0.1"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.2"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.3"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" Version="3.0.4"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.2"

Comment: "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0"
"WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.1"

Comment: Hi Ryan! I really appreciate your effort, and obviously it's some mess I have in my project. Thing is that I have a shared core assembly between my webapp and those functions, and I wanted to inject all the log setup the same way. Looks like that's too much. So I'll strip down the log implementations for the webjob. Then, following the documented steps, I'm sure I can set it up.
Thank you very much again!!